# Push data dynamically created into array

Tags: javascript

I have a constructor property that expects an array of type (just for example) `Dog`. Rather than creating an array, filling it with Dogs and then passing that to the property I would like to create that array dynamically in a for-loop.

So instead of

```
(...) new ConstructorFoo({
    property: [
        new Dog("1"),
        new Dog("2")
    ]
});
```

I would like to use something like this:

```
(...) new ConstructorFoo({
    property: function() {
        var d = [];
        for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            d.push(new Dog(i));
        }
        return d;
    }
});
```

But as far as I understand this throws an exception because of type mismatch. `property` expects an array of dogs but gets a function (correct?).

I hope my question makes sense.

Comment: "correct?" - `property` doesn't expect anything, it's an attribute in an object, being passed to `ConstructorFoo`. `ConstructorFoo` expects its argument to be of a certain form, and we can't tell you exactly what unless you show `ConstructorFoo`. If you just want to create an array before passing it to `ConstructorFoo`, then georg's answer should serve you well. If something is being used to `defineProperty`, then you will need to show us what you are doing.

Answer (score 4):

Just call it in place:

```
(...) new ConstructorFoo({
    property: (function() {
        var d = [];
        for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            d.push(new Dog(i));
        }
        return d;
    })()
});
```

Comment: Thank you. That's exactly what I was looking for but failed to find the correct words to do a decent search.